# R: Create a new data frame from an existing data frame to study changes in one variable (column)

Tags: r

For example, let's say I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
1   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6000    0.75346
2   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6050    0.72079
3   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6100    0.69229
4   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6150    0.66689
5   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6200    0.64382
6   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6250    0.62269
7   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6300    0.60313
# and so on
```

In this data frame, I want find out whenever the value in column 6 equals 6550, column 2 = 0.00030, column 3 = 0.75000, and column 4 = 0.50 (perhaps to study how a dependent variable changes when the value in column 5 changes). If it does, I want to create a new data frame using all the rows that satisfy this condition. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you.

- First `pivot_longer`
- Then check for condition with `case_when`
- Then `pivot_wider` to get the new dataframe

```
library(tidyverse)

# your data last line added to met condition
df <- tribble(
  ~col1, ~col2, ~col3, ~col4, ~col5, ~col6,
0.00038, 0.75053, 0.50, 35, 6000, 0.75346, 
0.00038, 0.75053, 0.50, 35, 6050, 0.72079, 
0.00038, 0.75053, 0.50, 35, 6100, 0.69229, 
0.00038, 0.75053, 0.50, 35, 6150, 0.66689, 
0.00038, 0.75053, 0.50, 35, 6200, 0.64382, 
0.00038, 0.75053, 0.50, 35, 6250, 0.62269, 
0.00038, 0.75053, 0.50, 35, 6300, 0.60313,
0.00038, 0.00030, 0.75000, 0.50, 6300, 6550) # added to fullfill true

# your conditions
# column 6 equals 6550, 
# column 2 = 0.00030,
# column 3 = 0.75000, 
# and column 4 = 0.50 

df1 <- df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("col"), names_to = "Cols", values_to= "Values") %>% 
    mutate(check = case_when(Cols == "col6" & Values == 6550 ~ "col6TRUE",
                             Cols == "col2" & Values == 0.00030 ~ "col2TRUE",
                             Cols == "col3" & Values == 0.75000 ~ "col3TRUE",
                             Cols == "col4" & Values == 0.50 ~ "col4TRUE")
    ) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(check)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Cols, values_from = Values)
```

Comment: Hi, I get the error `Error: cols must select at least one column.
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred`